# Distribution server in-place upgrade, Replication upgrade fails

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, windows-server

I have distribution database in AG, and want to upgrade two distributor servers from 2019dev to 2022dev, so when I run upgrade on secondary it completes, but SQL Server Replication upgrade fails with the following error:
`There was an error executing the Replication upgrade scripts. See the SQL Server error log for details.`
Does someone know how to resolve it or a right way to in-place upgrade distribution AG?

Tried restarting server and *removing replica, upgrade, adding back* cycle

Comment: Did you see the error log? What does it say?

Comment: Exception encountered while running sp_vupgrade_replication: Could not open distribution database distribution because it is offline or being recovered. Replication settings and system objects could not be upgraded. Be sure this database is available and run sp_vupgrade_replication again. And running the sp again doesn't help

Comment: Post the errors in the question itself. Without the error log there's absolutely no information, much less useful information. Right now it's impossible to even guess what you tried, much less what's wrong. You don't just upgrade an availability group.

Comment: `And running the sp again doesn't help` if the database is down, re-running a stored procedure will still fail. `Could not open distribution database distribution because it is offline or being recovered` that's a major problem. Is the database OK? Was it deleted? Is it offline?

Comment: it's ok wasn't deleted, online and in AG, replication goes